# JavaScript Загрузка файлов Blob

Tags: javascript

Доброе время суток, загрузить файл по уже зарание указанному пути.

как тут

```js
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener('load', function() {
    document.getElementById('file').innerText = this.result;
  });
  reader.readAsText(document.querySelector('input').files[0]);

});
```

```html
<input type="file">
<button id="myBtn">Try it</button>
<pre id="file"></pre>
```

но без веб, допустим так

```js
var input = "C:\katalog.xls";
```

На выходе готовый **Blob**

Доп

есть такой вариант, но тут непонятно как указать файл с диска, только можно файл из корневой папки.

```js
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
   
 oReq.open("GET", "*.doc", true);
 
 //oReq.open("GET", jsonObject, true);
 
 oReq.responseType = "blob";
 
 oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
   var blob = oReq.response;
   insertFile(blob);
   // ...
 };

 oReq.send();
```

Comment: в чем заключается вопрос?

Comment: Каким образом загрузить файл без html формы, если указать путь напрямую не выходит так как элемент не Blob, как подцепить файл и перевести его в Blob

Comment: в браузере - никак.

Comment: Вот тут ты ошибаешься, есть такой способ, но он мне слегка не подходит.  var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
   
 oReq.open("GET", "", true);
 
 //oReq.open("GET", jsonObject, true);
 
 oReq.responseType = "blob";
 
 oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
   var blob = oReq.response;
   insertFile(blob);
   // ...
 };

 oReq.send();

Comment: Я не ошибаюсь - XMLHttpRequest - позволяет сделать **запрос на сервер**, так как ты хочешь взять локальный файл - тебе это никак не поможет и не относится к основному вопросу.

Comment: если же ты открываешь локальную страничку по протоколу `file:///` то сервером выступает твой локальный компьютер, но и тут все ограничено и нет свободного доступа к файловой системе.